# How to assign, clear and get value of a hidden field in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Consider a hiddenfield in the page `HfId`

```
<input type="hidden" id="HfId"/>
```

How to assign,clear and get value of a hidden field in jquery? ANy suggestion...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [Element Selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) of jQuery is exactly designed for this. It allows you to select all elements which fit the given name, id or class:

```
$("a")       // Get all a-elements
$("#id")     // Get all elements with the id "id"
$(".class")  // Get all elements with the class "class"
```

The visibility or other properties of the element does not interfere with that, as it is still present in the DOM of the document.

Fields have the overloaded function `val()`, `val($value)` which allows you to get and set the value of the field:

```
$val = $("#HfId").val();  // Get
$("#HfId").val("");       // Clear
$("#HfId").val($newVal);  // Set
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#HfId").val("pony");
var x = $("#HfId").val();
```